# Incorrect query syntax for a SELECT in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I get this exception when I'm trying to run a simple SELECT query with my Visual Studio project:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

My code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Claudia\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp7\WindowsFormsApp7\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        loadlist();
    }

    private void loadlist()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        cn.Open();

        // here I get the exception
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table";

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("No items");
        }

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

I tried all methods I've known, I also tried to recreate the project form nothing but I get this exception every time. When I run the project, database is disconnecting. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Is `Table` the full name of the table? Or is it `dbo.Table`?

Comment: Your tables' name is really `Table`?

Comment: MySQL and ms sql server are two different products. Pls always use the appropriate product tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Table` is a keyword for SQL Server. You need to escape it by wrapping it in square brackets:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
```

Btw: `Table` is of course not a very good table name.

Comment: Also, the real table name is probably `dbo.Table` or something.

Comment: @Tudor well, `dbo` always seemed optional to me, but it may also work. The name however would still be `Table` and `dbo.Table` the full-qualified name.

Comment: I think MySQL uses backtick instead of []

Comment: @Steve that's right (afaik - didn't use mysql), but OP used `SqlConnection` etc...(didn't check the tags)